# Unknown Document Type Error while using LLamaIndex with Azure OpenAI

Tags: python, azure, azure-openai, llama, llama-index

I'm trying to reproduce the code from documentation: https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/examples/customization/llms/AzureOpenAI.html and receive the following error after `index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents)`:

```
raise ValueError(f"Unknown document type: {type(document)}")
ValueError: Unknown document type: <class 'llama_index.legacy.schema.Document'>
```

Due to the fact that all these generative ai libraries are being constantly updated, I have to switch the import of `SimpleDirectoryReader` and make it like `from llama_index.legacy.readers.file.base import SimpleDirectoryReader`
All the rest is actually the same with tutorial (using `llama_index==0.10.18` and python of version `3.9.16`). I have spent already several hours on that and actually don't have ideas how should I proceed. So if somebody can assist with that - it would be super helpful :)

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because of the type of document you are passing for `VectorStoreIndex.from_documents()`.

When you import `SimpleDirectoryReader` from legacy modules, the type of document is `llama_index.legacy.schema.Document`.

[image]

You are passing that to `VectorStoreIndex`, which is imported from core modules: `from llama_index.core import VectorStoreIndex`.

The document you referred to is correct for **core** modules, and you can import `SimpleDirectoryReader` as `from llama_index.core import VectorStoreIndex, SimpleDirectoryReader`, and everything will work fine.

If you wish to use **legacy** modules, then use the code below.

```py
from llama_index.legacy.llms.azure_openai import AzureOpenAI
from llama_index.legacy.embeddings.azure_openai import AzureOpenAIEmbedding
from llama_index.legacy import SimpleDirectoryReader, VectorStoreIndex, ServiceContext
import logging
import sys

logging.basicConfig(
    stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO
)  # logging.DEBUG for more verbose output
logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout))

api_key = "3c9xxxyyyyzzzzzssssssdb9"
azure_endpoint = "https://<resource_name>.openai.azure.com/"
api_version = "2023-07-01-preview"

llm = AzureOpenAI(
    model="gpt-4",
    deployment_name="gpt4",
    api_key=api_key,
    azure_endpoint=azure_endpoint,
    api_version=api_version,
)

# You need to deploy your own embedding model as well as your own chat completion model
embed_model = AzureOpenAIEmbedding(
    model="text-embedding-ada-002",
    deployment_name="embeding1",
    api_key=api_key,
    azure_endpoint=azure_endpoint,
    api_version=api_version,
)

documents = SimpleDirectoryReader(input_files=["./data/s1.txt"]).load_data()
type(documents[0])

service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(
    llm=llm, embed_model=embed_model
)

index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents, service_context=service_context)
```

Output:

```py
query = "What is the model name and who updated it last?"
query_engine = index.as_query_engine()
answer = query_engine.query(query)
print("query was:", query)
print("answer was:", answer)
```

[image]

Here, when using **legacy** modules, all tools and models should be imported from the same legacy modules, and an additional service context is used for the vector store index.

Comment: great answer, that saved a lot of time. thanks!